# Automated Deployment and Configuration using node.js

Tags: node.js, automated-deployment

We are working on some Java EE based distributed application. It involves multiple message brokers (RabbitMQ, HornetQ), multiple databases (HBase, MongoDB, Rracle) and the JBoss application server.

We want to manage (deploy and configure) these nodes using node.js.

Is that possible? Are there any readily made frameworks available for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [NPM registry](https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/build) there are probably 50 entries under `build`.

The most used ones appear to be [`jake`](https://npmjs.org/package/jake) (and `utils`), [`grunt`](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt) and [`gears`](https://npmjs.org/package/gears). They have lots of regular downloads, so you'll probably want to start there. That stated, I'm unsure about the tooling for managing all of the DBs in question. You'll want to check the status of those drivers. I know that MongoDB has first-class Node.JS support, but the others may not be so lucky.